# Where can I find research on wallet fingerprinting?

Tags: privacy, taint-analysis

@raw_avocado asks on [Twitter](https://twitter.com/raw_avocado/status/1318040355690942465?s=20):

> I remember reading at some point something about how you can identify
> transactions made by specific wallets because they have a specific
> fingerprint because of how they construct transactions.
>
> Are there any public stats on this?

Where can we find more information on the unique fingerprints of wallets? Is there a website that tracks this information or maybe an academic paper?

Comment: I am also interested in the answer for this question. I met someone in a bitcoin meetup here in India who had done some research but didn't share details with me. Will see if I can get something interesting. Also the discussion in this issue is interesting: https://github.com/zkSNACKs/WalletWasabi/issues/3625 and `rbf`, `discourageFeeSniping`, `version`, `lockTime` randomized in https://github.com/dgarage/NBXplorer/pull/262/commits/f43919ba8f8bd7cf1aacc699a43a9532ca9357a5

Answer (score 5):

Is [this the research article](https://b10c.me/mempool-observations/3-blockchaincom-recommendations/) you are thinking about? It's blockchain.com wallet fingerprinting mostly on the basis of feerates by 0xB10C.

Comment: oh right, mempool.observer is a great resource for that.